# Amazon API Gateway Import From Swagger Error - Not taking Generics

Tags: amazon-web-services, generics, swagger, generic-programming, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create new APIGateway via import from Swagger, but having validation errors:

The particular class causing the issue is our PaginationModel class.

Code model definition:

```
public class PaginationModel<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> items { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger file section representing Generic PaginationModel for a particular type:

```
*"PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]":{"type":"object","properties":{"items":    {"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/DepartmentUIModel"}},"offset":    {"format":"int32","type":"integer"},"totalCount":{"format":"int32","type":"integer"}}}*
```

Error when importing Swagger file into Amazon API Gateway:

*Unable to create model for 'PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]': Model name must be alphanumeric: PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]*

Changed the '[' with '<' and '{' but not solving the problem.

Other than creating specific Pagination models for all types, is there a way I can make the API Gateway understand this particular output from Swagger?

Comment: You're best off using the `allOf` construct to wrap generic, reusable patterns and type-specific models.  The model `PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]` does not work as a generic in any context of swagger.

Comment: Thank you Fehguy, but not sure if you understood the question. We have used a current swagger definition and then imported into http://editor.swagger.io/ - no issues, as well as into a free version of https://restlet.com/. A swagger definition file does not display any errors when loaded into those tools. BUT swagger definition can not be successfully imported into AWS API Gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fehguy's answer is more helpful to you, but the specific error you're getting from API Gateway is just extra validation that we have on top of what is in the Swagger spec.

> Unable to create model for 'PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]': Model name must be alphanumeric: PaginationModel[DepartmentUIModel]

Model names must be alphanumeric, meaning they have to match the regex "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

Comment: Thank you Jack. Seeing the Regex, I can understand I have no choice but to have in the Swagger output alphanumeric only. I'm curious though why the extra validation on top of what Swagger already does. Seems to me it should be sufficient enough. Anyway, I'll comply with the current limits.